# WooCommerce - Restriction of one category per order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I searched in the different messages but I can't find exactly what I am looking for ... Could you help me?

I found this code which almost matches what I need.
It prevents the addition of new products if a product is already present in the cart.

I would also like to add the additional condition which is that if I have products in my cart, it is not possible to add the product. And show an alert message.

```php
// Add custom Theme Functions here
// Custom conditional function that checks for parent product categories
function has_parent_term( $product_id ) {
    // HERE set your targeted product category SLUG
    $category_slug = 'box-dejeuner'; //  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====

    // Convert category term slug to term id
    $category_id   = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat')->term_id;
    $parent_term_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }
    return in_array( $category_id, $parent_term_ids );
}

// Avoid add to cart others product categories when "box-dejeuner" is in cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'specific_category_avoid_add_to_cart_others', 20, 3 );
function specific_category_avoid_add_to_cart_others( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() || has_parent_term( $product_id ) ) {
        return $passed;
    }

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( has_parent_term( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Si une box d&eacute;jeuner est pr&eacute;sente dans votre panier, vous ne pouvez pas commander un autre produit. Veuillez finaliser votre commande de la box et repasser une nouvelles commandes pour vos autres produits.&nbsp;', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' ); // Display a custom error notice
            return false; // Avoid add to cart
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

Comment: The additional function checking for categories is unnecessary,, use [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459387/allow-only-one-item-in-cart-from-defined-product-categories-in-woocommerce Get started and adjust your question where necessary (if you not found the solution in the meantime)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... Sorry but I'm a developing newbie.
In fact, I do not have the impression that that answers my problem ...?
In the code I indicated, if I have the "box-dejeuner" in my basket, I can no longer add a new product.
On the other hand, I would like not to be able to add the product "Box-dejeuner" if I already have other products in my basket.

Comment: I have not indicated that this answers your question, otherwise I would have marked it as a duplication. I just indicated that your existing code can be written more efficient